# Mvvmcross Upgrade to 5.6.3 error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Dialog'

Tags: xamarin.android, styles, themes, mvvmcross, upgrade

I just upgraded MvvmCross from 5.4.2 to 5.6.3 an now I get the following errors
for everything in my styles.xml file and my themes.xml file.

I have not changes hte target SDK. I just upgraded to 5.6.3, I get these errors and the Resources.Designer.cs file is not being updated when I build the application

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Dialog'.   Styles.xml  2   
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat'.  Styles.xml  2   
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat'.  themes.xml  18  
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid'. themes.xml  18  
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ListPopupWindow'. themes.xml  18  
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'.   themes.xml  18  
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown'.   themes.xml  18  
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView'.   themes.xml  18  
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.  themes.xml  20  
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode'.  themes.xml  20  
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Spinner'. themes.xml  20  
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.   themes.xml  23  
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.   themes.xml  23
```

Comment: Clean and build again. Also make sure that versions match all around and Android Support library versions match too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this must have been an Visual Studio Nuget upgrade problem, when I regressed back to 5.4.2, the same issue was present. Luckily I had a shelveset, so I got the latest code and re-applied the shelveset and the build worked.

I then upgraded from 5.4.2 -> 5.5.2 -> 5.6.3 and the problem did not re-occurr